# Тормозит jQuery анимация на смартфонах

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем есть спойлер jQuery на сайте и когда работаешь с ним на компьютере все хорошо. Анимация закрытия-открытия плавная, но при просмотре с мобильника анимация тормозит и никакой плавности. При этом качество тормозов растет на слабых телефонах (на 4S тормоза страшнее, чем на Xperia M4). Как и с помощью чего решают такую проблему?

Код спойлера:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#title').click(function(){
               jQuery('.spoiler-body').hide(400);
               $(this).parent().children('#body').slideToggle(400);
               return false;
             });
             });
</script>
```

Comment: видимо слабый процессор на телефоне.

Comment: Да, согласен, но как-то же решают проблемы с производительностью на смартфонах наверное...

Comment: return уберите, скорость анимации поставьте на минимум, 100, и зачем вы скрываете все `.spoiler-body`?

Comment: Там просто несколько спойлеров на странице, скрываю чтобы если один открыт, то все остальные были закрыты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случаях скрытия, показа блоков на jquery, тормоза начинаются из-за подсчета размеров блока. Смотреть надо не только скрипт, но и стили css. Если возможно задать жесткий размер разворачиваемому блоку, то надо их задать. Хорошо расписано здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/72137/

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в тэге `<head></head>` подключено несколько версий jquery.
Нужно оставить одну..

Или еще возможно происходит Bubbling клика на другие теги (все зависти от того сколько их там).
Попробуйте вот так, может будет чуть быстрее работать т.к. событие (клик) будет завершатся на теге по которому кликнули.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#title').click(function(event){
               event.stopPropagation();
               jQuery('.spoiler-body').hide(400);
               $(this).parent().children('#body').slideToggle(400);
               return false;
             });
             });
</script>
```

И можете еще посмотреть http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ если так переделать, то должно всё быть плавно

Comment: Нет, там все хорошо, перепроверил.

Comment: event.stopPropagation(); Зачем минусовать )) у меня, например всё очень тяжело работало, когда было несколько версий jquery. Теория имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: только что поправил. event.stopPropagation();  для события click

Comment: Чуть-чуть плавнее стало, но дерганья все равно заметны..